# Change are not being reflected across the references

Tags: c++, reference

I am doing an assignment in which we are supposed to code a very basic scenario of a company to manage their products. So when a new product is entered we are supposed to check if it already exists (which we are supposed to do by comparing the names of the products with the name of the product entered; empty products have an empty string as their name), if we do not find it, then we are supposed to add it to the list of products of the company(there can be a maximum of 3 product only so I am checking each one of them individually).

```
class Store : public Product {
public:
        ...
        Product& return_product_1() {return product1;}
        Product& return_product_2() {return product2;}
        Product& return_product_3() {return product3;}

private:
        Product product1;
        Product product2;
        Product product3;
        ...
        
};
```

So I thought that I can use a function which returns a reference to an object which is currently empty (Since all the three Product objects are individually stored in the class, so adding or removing an object is simply asking for its details from the user or setting the data members to NULL respectively), so I created the following function to find a particular `Product` object. I pass a string `n` to check whether any `Product` object has a same name as `n` and I also pass an empty `Product` object so that i can make `p` synonymous with the returned `Product` since both of them are references. ( I did this because i wanted to return both the correct `Product` object as well as a boolean. I could have used `std::pair` to return both of them,  but i did not wanted to do that.

```
bool StarberksInterface::search(string n, Product& p) {     

        if(store.return_product_1().product_name() == n) {
                p = store.return_product_1();
                return true;
        }
        else if(store.return_product_2().product_name() == n){
                p = store.return_product_2();
                return true;
        }
        else if(store.return_product_3().product_name() == n) {
                p = store.return_product_3();
                return true;
        }
        else return false;    // The function returns true when a Product object which the same name as the first parameter is found
}
```

`product_name` is defined as

```
std::string product_name() const {return name;}
```

where `name` is a data member of type `std::string` of `Product` class.

The function `search(string, Product&)` is called using the function call `search("", p);` where i pass an empty string to check for a currently empty product and p is declared as `Product p;`.

I declare another `Product` object `Product temp = input();`, where `input` is declared as `Product input();` and it asks the user for the information about the product and returns a `Product` object. I have overloaded the assignment operator for `Product` class.

I then write

```
p = temp;
```

Now I was thinking was that since `return_product_1` would have returned a reference, and `p` was assigned the value of `return_product_1`, therefore `p` and    `product1` should be synonymous ( Assuming that the `search` function initially finds that `product1` indeed has an empty string as a name). Any changes made to `p` should be reflected in `product1`, but it seems that is not the case. I wanted that the details of `temp` should also be assigned to `product1` since i assigned `temp` to `p`.  Is there something wrong with my code or perhaps my logic?
Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: References are not reassignable. When you create a reference to object, it will always point to that particular object and nothing else. `p = store.return_product_1();` calls copy assignment operator - you still have two separate objects, but now `p` will have values copied from `store.product1`.

Comment: You could instead have `Product* StarberksInterface::search(const std::string& name)`. Also, any time you find yourself defining a list of variables like `var1`, `var2`, etc. all with the same type, consider changing to a `std::array<Type, Size>` or `std::vector<Type>` instead, so that it takes much less code to use them.

Comment: Usually, when you are trying to bend the rules of a language, there is a problem with your design.

Comment: @aschepler I completely get the use of the pointer, but isn't it safe to assume that C++ references behave as pointers.. I know the differences between references and pointers.. But as @Yksisarvinen stated, since ```p = store.return_product_1``` calls copy assignment operator but, ```p``` is a reference to a ```Product``` and ```store.return_product_1``` also returns a reference, so i was thinking that the changes which I do in ```p``` should also be reflected back in ```product1```

Comment: @CeNiEi You still have two different `Product` objects: the member of the `Store` object, and the object named `temp`. There's no way to combine them to be just one object.